# Why is my property a potential leak and how can I fix it?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, release

I have a **UIScrollView** in my **UIViewController** defined as this in my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView * imageScrollView;

@end
```

Then in my .m file I have the following:

```
@synthesize imageScrollView = _imageScrollView;
```

I read that this will automatically create the _imageScrollView that I would normally type in the .h file? (UIScrollView * _imageScrollView)

I like it, because it removes duplicate code from my .h files. Now in my **loadView** I do the rest:

```
self.imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0 - 20.0 - 49.0)];
[_imageScrollView setDelegate:self];
[_imageScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[_imageScrollView setBounces:NO];
[_imageScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[_imageScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[_imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0 * 3.0, 480.0 - 20.0 - 49.0)];
```

And in the **dealloc** release and nil:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
[_imageScrollView release], _imageScrollView = nil;

[super dealloc];
}
```

Now after a build Xcode is telling me this:

```
Potential leak of an object allocated on line #linenumber
```

This will go away when I change this:

```
self.imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0 - 20.0 - 49.0)];
```

to this:

```
self.imageScrollView = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0 - 20.0 - 49.0)] autorelease];
```

Why do I need to autorelease this when I'm release it in dealloc? What am I doing wrong?

This memory warning only occurs in Xcode on my iMac with Lion installed, not on my macbook with snow leopard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `imageScrollView` property is declared to be a `retain` property. This means that when you set it, the accessor (which is generated by `@synthesize`) automatically retains the value. If you don't want this behavior, you should declare your property to be `assign`. (But you *do* want this behavior in this case.)

Anyway, thus your object is retained twice, once in your code, and once by the accessor, so it's never released. Always remember that `self.imageScrollView =` is just like `[self setImageScrollView:]`, and that stuff happens in there!

(And last, the memory warning only occurs on Lion because the old Xcode isn't noticing the error, not because the error isn't there.)

Comment: Ah yes, it makes sense to me now.. (It seems I can't put an enter in here) How can I avoid the autorelease? Or is it the only (and best) option in this case? Normally when I create a temporary object I release it right after I'm done with it. Isn't it bad to fill the autorelease pool with stuff like this when there is possibly a way to just retain it once at all times?

Comment: Autorelease is probably your best option here. It's true that the autorelease pool can be slow, but only if the code in question is called literally thousands of times. If you were allocating a lot of stuff in a tight loop, then you might want to create a temporary variable to point to your new view, set imageScrollView to it, then call release on your temp variable. That way you can set before releasing, so you don't need to autorelease. (But again, only if you've noticed it being slow.)

Comment: You mean like this: UIScrollView * imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init]; [self setImageScrollView:imageScrollView]; [imageScrollView release]; The app is not being slow (or I'm not noticing it at least), but for any future projects I just want to get this clear (but I think it is now, thank you again!)

Comment: Yes, just like that (assuming you don't already have an instance variable named `imageScrollView`, which you might).

Comment: @Rick van der Linde: The performance implications of autorelease in this case are really and truly negligible. It is essentially one or two no-op message sends.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined your property with the `retain` option. This means that when you assign an object to that property, it will be retained—you "take ownership" of the object. That's good in this case, because you want the `UIScrollView` to stick around while you need it. I should note that you also own any object returned from methods whose name begins with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`.

So, looking at your code you can see that you own `UIScrollView` that you create with `alloc`, but then you claim ownership *again* when you store it in the property. This means that the memory will never be reclaimed. By calling `autorelease`, you relinquish ownership of the object before assigning it to the property, meaning that calling `release` in `dealloc` will work as intended.

I suggest you read over the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) and the [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) section of The Objective-C Programming Language document.

Comment: Thank you for you answer :) Sadly it's impossible to give two persons the right answer! I will do a read up again :)